How to choose maven plugins versions : default versions or last available versions or others?
Maven allows you to define the version of its own plugins, for example the version of maven-compiler-plugin or that of maven-jar-plugin... If you do not define the versions of these plugins, Maven uses (resolves) its plugins with default versions, which were first defined in the "super pom", then in some xml configuration files and are now defined directly in java sources named Providers as mentioned here and here.
I read that a good development practice is to systematically define the versions of Maven plugins in the pom.xml to avoid that the build result is different when a new version of Maven is used.
But which versions of Maven plugins should I choose?
For example, I have to use the Maven RPM package of RHEL 8, which unless I am mistaken corresponds to Maven 3.5.4.
Is it better for me to choose and write in the pom.xml the versions of the default plugins defined in Maven 3.5.4 or to choose the latest versions of the Maven plugins currently available ?

First do not use such old Maven version anymore (https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) use most recent 3.9.X version ... also define all plugins in your pom file and use the most recent versions (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ...

Thank you very much @khmarbaise for your quick and expert response.
